# Depth problem using wp_list_pages for subnavigation

Tags: navigation, children

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for some time now, and I can't seem to find one.

I have created a submenu using the following code from the Codex:

```
<?php
 if($post->post_parent) {
 $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
 $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
 }

 else {
 $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
 $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->ID);
 }
 if ($children) { ?>

 <h2> <?php echo $titlenamer; ?> </h2>
 <ul>
 <?php echo $children; ?>
 </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

This worked fine until I added siblings to a child menu.

I want the menu to work like this:

- Main menu
- - Submenu (Children)
- - - Siblings

But using the before code above I get this (as show in this image http://www.inlusiondesign.dk/images/stories/wp_list_pages-problem.png):

- Main menu
- - Submenu (Children)
- - Siblings

If I where to click e.g. "Test 1" everything is fine again - I suppose this is because it hasn't got any children.

I have tried using "depth=2" in various places, but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wordpress out of the box displays menu the way you want. You just need to do the css to ajdust the display. A simple wp_list_pages will spit out all the pages the way you want them.

Comment: Down-voting for being a "drive-by" question. I'll change to an up-vote if the OP comes back to follow up on the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `depth=1` rather than `depth=2`.

You are specifying, via the `child_of` argument, that you want to display *children of the current Page's parent Page*. That means that the first level of hierarchy is the current Page (and any of its siblings). The *second* level of hierarchy would be *child* pages of the current Page (and of any of the current Page's siblings).

So, give `depth=1` a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the wp_nav_menu function and create menus in order to get the depth you want.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: I did actually do that first, but I would like to figure out how the wp_list_pages function works, since its a bit easier on sites with many nested pages.